# join array of images SQL

Tags: mysql, image, join

I got 2 tables ("ad" and "image").

"ad" contains many properties like ad.id, ad.detail, ...

"image" contains image.id, image.url, image.ad_id

I'd like to make ONE query that returns me a ad by id and all images associated like:

```
 ad : 
 - id: 107
 - details: a great ad
 - ...
 - images :
   - id : 1
   - url : toto.jpg
   - ad_id : 107
   - id : 2
   - url : titi.jpg
   - ad_id : 107
```

Can someone tell me if that's possible with MySQL and PDO?

Comment: This is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: Show us your attempt to use a `JOIN` and then add that to the question.  Then we'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN sounds like what you are looking for.

```
SELECT ad.id, ad.details, ... , images.id, images.url, ...
FROM ad
LEFT JOIN image
ON ad.id = image.ad_id
ORDER BY ad.id
```

If you want to use some SQL take a look at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Tutorials and examples can be found there on the other types of joins.